# Can't get randomized vertical line to work in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've tried to create the simplest vertical line with a random x value between 0-5 at each vertex, and an increase in 10px in the y value at a time. Why is my line not showing?

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  var y = 10;
  var r = 0;
  beginShape();
  vertex(0, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i += 10) {
    r = random(0, 5);
    console.log(r + " " + y);
    vertex(r, y);
    translate(r, y);
    y += 10;
  }
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to translate repeatedly without pushing/popping? If I remove `translate` I get something that seems plausible. Could you sketch out your expected result if that's not it? You might want to use `line()` to draw  lines rather than shapes but I'm not sure what you're going for.

Comment: I thought I wanted translate(). If I start at vertex 0,0, then let's say my next vertex is (2,10). I want to translate to that point, because let's say by random chance, my third vertex is also (2,10). If I don't translate, then the 3rd vertex will be in the exact same spot as the 2nd vertex. I want to continually force the line downward, no? If I push/pop every vertex, I will always be starting at 0,0 instead of at the previous vertex?

Comment: To further clarify on my understanding, I'm confused why the attached sketch doesn't draw a line from 0,0 to 20,20, and then the 2nd line goes from 20,20 to 30,35 https://editor.p5js.org/elliotmersch/sketches/gdLgKfOTe

Comment: Translating shifts the whole shape. The base offset accumulates all of your translates, plus whatever the vertex offsets are, which is way out of bounds of the canvas. Can you confirm that removing the `translate` call shows a line for you as it does for me? Playing with your new example is a good way to establish the behavior--it's unintuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the way `translate()` works in the context of a shape.

You may be under the impression that each translate moves the canvas a little bit, then you draw a vertex, then the next translate moves the canvas a bit, then you draw another vertex and so on.

Actually, all of the `translate()` calls that happen inside of the `beginShape()`/`endShape()` stack on top of each other, translating the whole, completed shape as defined by the offsets passed to each `vertex()` call way off canvas. The coordinates you log misleadingly don't take into account the translations.

The solution is basically to remove `translate()`, optionally just doing one translation up front to reposition the shape.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  var y = 10;
  var r = 0;
  beginShape();
  vertex(0, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i += 10) {
    r = random(0, 5);
    vertex(r, y);
    //translate(r, y); // <-- only change
    y += 10;
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

That said, I don't think shapes are appropriate here anyway since I believe they'll require you to draw an ugly-looking straight line from bottom to top to close out the shape. Using a series of lines seems to look better:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  push();
  translate(width / 2, 0);
  let lastX = 0;
  let lastY = 0;

  for (let y = 0; y <= height; y += 10) {
    const x = random(0, 5)
    line(lastX, lastY, x, y);
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
  }
  
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Looping the above gives:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < width; i += 5) {
    push();
    translate(i, 0);
    let lastX = 0;
    let lastY = 0;

    for (let y = 0; y <= height; y += 10) {
      const x = random(0, 5)
      line(lastX, lastY, x, y);
      lastX = x;
      lastY = y;
    }

    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot beginShape(LINES) also you should put translate outside of the beginShape endShape otherwise it will translate everything once. (So they will be at the same place and not all over the place).

I made this code after many trial and error, I don't know if it's the result you expected:

```js
function draw() {
  background(220);
  var y = 10;
  var r = 0;
  var random_old = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i += 10) {
    beginShape(LINES);
    r = random(0, 5);
    console.log(r + " " + y);
    vertex(r, y);
    y += 10;
    r = random(0, 5);
    vertex(r, y);
    endShape();
    translate((r - random_old) * 10, 0);
    random_old = r;
    y += 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.js"></script>
```